# How to find icon in new Microsoft's Start menu?

Tags: windows-8, icons, start-screen

Suppose I want to find MyProgram's icon in new great superior progressive and very charming Microsoft's start menu of Windows 8.1?

I press Windows button and this wonderwork appears. I starting to type: "M", "Y", "P", "R" and... Aliluyya! my program is found!

Then I right click it... and... what is it? There is no "Pin to Start" entry. There is only "Unpin from Start" entry.

What does this mean? This mean that icon is ALREADY SOMEWHERE on Start.

Where?

How to find it?

NOTE: I don't want to find a program. I want to find IT'S ICON (or how did they name it? wondericon?) for example, to drag it to another place.

**HILARIOUS**

Microsoft forgot to make a search, but minuses are going to me!

Comment: Not specified. I need just to search among pinned icons. If there are two different methods of searching then please answer both.

Comment: @Ramhound give 2 answers if they exist.

Comment: you may have hit your limit on the icons and its on the next page, normally towards the bottom right theres a down arrow, clicking it will let you see all the programs in the start menu.

Comment: @Ramhound as you like. But remember, that user is not obliged to know programming language when searching, it is ubnormal requirement.

Comment: @Dims - You are suppose to ask questions that are actual problems.  The more talk about "a user' makes me believe this isn't a problem you actual have.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will help you out, I used windows 8 when it was in beta, so I don't remember much of the technical things.
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/add-remove-programs-windows-8-start-screen/

edit: According to the link I provided, if you right click or touch on the icon until there is a check next to it, a menu will pop up on the bottom of the screen and you can click "open file location".

Comment: My question is about already pinned programs. Suppose you have 1000 pinned programs. How to find one of them?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Ramhound do you think it is normal if finding depends on application programming language?

Comment: @Dims - Absolutely. A Windows program does not require you to assign an .icon file. If none exists a default icon based on the file extension will be used ( which is defined by the user itself ).

Comment: @Ramhound so, the question persists. User knows he has program "MyProgram" amongst pinned icons, he does not know, which language it was written in, and wants to find it.

Comment: @Dims - The problem is that there isn't a single method.  There are programs that can extract the .icon file from most desktop programs.  Any number of methods will work.  Having a question with a half dozen different approaches to a single problem indicates the question's scope might be to broad.  In any event I am done trying to drag the information out of you so that I would have been able to answer it.